# How to filter during angular2 service call

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to develop a mockup on Angular 2. In this case, I have a model called `Layer`, in which has multiple JSON entries:

#### Layer.ts

```
export class Layer {
  model: number;
  layer: string;
  loaded: number;
}
```

I also have a mock-layer injector for the mockup:

#### mock-layer.ts

```
import { Layer } from './layer';

export const LAYERS: Layer[] = [
  {model: 9.1, layer: 'SIF', loaded: 1},
  {model: 9.1, layer: 'AW', loaded: 1},
  {model: 9.1, layer: 'DW', loaded: 1},
  {model: 8.7, layer: 'SIF', loaded: 1},
  {model: 8.7, layer: 'AW', loaded: 1},
  {model: 8.7, layer: 'DW', loaded: 1}
];
```

In the real world, I would only return 1 model '9.1' or '8.7'.  However, I am in mock-up phase, and I'm pulling my two examples right now.

To service this data, I have a layer service:

#### layer.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { LAYERS } from './mock-layers';

@Injectable()
export class LayerService {
  getLayers() {
    return Promise.resolve(LAYERS);
  }

}
```

The function `getLayers()` returns all of the layer records.
For the example I am making, how do I return only those layers that fit a certain variable (e.g. `Model = '9.1'`)?

Comment: *How to filter Promise* By filtering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) before creating the `Promise`:

```
getLayers() {
  return Promise.resolve(LAYERS.filter(layer => layer.model === 9.1));
}
```

See [**demo plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfLR0ONMT9NqCNZQo2it?p=preview).

---

## Update: per coments, *Why `===` and not `=`?*

`=` is attribution, so:

```
LAYERS.filter(layer => layer.model = 9.1)
```

Is just plain wrong in this case. It is not filtering anything, it is (try it out in the plunker) basically overwriting every `layer.model` to `9.1`.

`===`, on the other hand, is the ***strict equality*** operator:

```
LAYERS.filter(layer => layer.model === 9.1)
```

The code above will result in a array where the contents are every `LAYERS` element that have the `model` property **strictly equal** to `9.1`.

To understand more the "strictly" part, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1850609).

Comment: Okay, glad it helped. I was working on a plunker to demonstrate it, since I already made it, here it is anyway: http://plnkr.co/edit/RfLR0ONMT9NqCNZQo2it?p=preview  cheers!

Comment: Oh, just an important point: the correct is `layer.model === 9.1`, not `layer.model = 9.1`!

Comment: got it.  why === and not =?

Comment: that's awesome. Thanks much